# Javascript Google Cloud Function try to get new added value in FirebaseDatabase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I followed the introduction of firebase to trigger if something has changed in my Database. I just want to log the new added values, but unfortunately it doesn't work. My Database structure looks like the following:

```
  "Chat" : {

      "-LGe_0ak8UOv9jFRukpZ" : {
         "-LGe_3FgL6JkM-VQsg3K" : {
           "Message" : "heiii na du",
           "createdByUser" : "6dB5rWfSIwez3gO0N0ClBwFJKu53",
           "ts" : 1530796459
          },
       "-LgeqadfFEA" : {
         "Message" : "yo",
         "createdByUser" : "asfdasdfasdfasdf",
         "ts" : 123456677
  }
},
```

So now the last item was added to my database and normally, I should receive a log with the new value, but the method was never started. I didn't receive any error as well. Here is my Method:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/Chat')
 .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime 
Database.
const original = snapshot.val();
console.log('ts', context.params.pushId, original);
const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
// You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a 
Functions such as
// writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
// Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a 
Promise.
return snapshot.ref.parent.child('ts').set(uppercase);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not correctly specified the realtime database path
You can use a wildcard to watch for changes within all 'chats' path, otherwise from your code, the function is watching for addition of actual key-value pair within your specified path whereas your intention is to watch for creation of a child
Example : `functions.database.ref('/Chat/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
//Your execution
})`
This tells cloud functions to watch creation of any object within the 'chat' path
You can further access the pushId variable through `context.params.pushId`
Happy coding